# Custom drawn MDI child frame client rectangle and message issues

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mdi

I am trying to create a class derived from `CMDIChildWndEx` which draws the child frame in Windows 10 style (theme colored caption bar, single pixel borders with an transparent region outside those allowing sizing, no 3D frame) rather than the old-style pale blue default.

I am making progress on drawing the frame, setting the regions etc. but the client area, as drawn my the parent `CView` class is in the wrong location, my window won't move from top left of the main frame and it doesn't receive `OnLButtonDown` or `OnMouseMove` messages which I need to override to handle resizing, moving and system menu buttons, as the window no longer has a non-client area.

I initially tried  using `CMFCVisualManager` to handle this problem, but it does not touch MDI child frames. I briefly tried making it do so, and quickly gave up as `CMFCVisualManager` is practically undocumented and most of the member variables I'd need to access are protected.

I followed a couple of examples of creating custom drawn SDI applications and adapted some of this code to my needs.

The first problem I ran into is that, in my overridden `OnNcPaint` function, `GetWindowDC()` is not returning the device context for the entire window, only a sub-region (slightly larger than the client rectangle, not the window rectangle). I found that I had to call `GetParent()->GetWindowDC()` in order to get the "correct" DC, correct at least in that its clip rectangle is the correct size (the same size as the window region I set). I suspect having had to call the parent DC is the root cause of the second problem...

The second problem is that the client area received by the `CView` class in its `OnDraw` function is in the wrong place. It is located (initially) 4 pixels down and to the right of the top left of my window, not below my caption bar. I suspect the problem here is that I'm missing something in defining my custom drawn non-client area (and therefore the offset to the desired client area). I had thought that defining the window region (in `OnCreateClient` and`OnSize`) as being offset above and to the left of the client rectangle (i.e. the window region has negative top left coordinates) would do this for me, but it seems not. I assume I need to override `OnNcCalcSize`, I haven't tried this yet.

Related to the second problem, the window does not resize properly. If I resize the window (using the base NC region at the top or left of my window), the client area resizes as expected, but my window stays at the upper left of the main frame client area. Again, I suspect this is related to having had to use `GetParent()->GetWindowDC()`.

The final problem, is that my window does not receive `OnLButtonDown` or `OnMouseMove` messages. It does receive OnNcLButtonDown and OnNcMouseMove, but this isn't really helpful as the non-client area is wrong (again, I assume I probably need to override `OnNcCalcSize` and possibly handle `WM_NCHITTEST`).

I won't show the entire class, obviously, as that would be a waste of space and the specifics of calculating and drawing the frame aren't really relevant. But here are the essential functions I haver overridden.

OnCreateClient:

```
BOOL CChildFrameEx::OnCreateClient(LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs, CCreateContext* pContext)
{
// Get client rectangle
CRect rectClient;
GetClientRect(&rectClient);

// Calculate new region
CRect rectRegion;
rectRegion = CRect(rectClient.left - m_nWindowClipPad - 1, rectClient.top - m_nCaptionHeight - 2 - m_nWindowClipPad, rectClient.right + m_nWindowClipPad + 1, rectClient.bottom + m_nWindowClipPad + 1);

m_rgnWindow.Detach();
m_rgnWindow.CreateRectRgnIndirect(rectRegion);

m_rectWindow = rectRegion;

// Set new region
VERIFY(SetWindowRgn(m_rgnWindow, TRUE));

return CMDIChildWndEx::OnCreateClient(lpcs, pContext);
}
```

LoadFrame:

```
BOOL CChildFrameEx::LoadFrame(UINT nIDResource, DWORD dwDefaultStyle, CWnd* pParentWnd, CCreateContext* pContext)
{
BOOL bReturn;
bReturn = CMDIChildWndEx::LoadFrame(nIDResource, dwDefaultStyle, pParentWnd, pContext);

if (bReturn) {
    ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, WS_CLIPCHILDREN);
    ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
}

return bReturn;
}
```

OnNcPaint:

```
void CChildFrameEx::OnNcPaint()
{
CDC* pDC = GetParent()->GetWindowDC();
.
.
.
}
```

OnSize:

```
void CChildFrameEx::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
// Get client rectangle
CRect rectClient;
GetClientRect(&rectClient);

// Calculate new region
CRect rectRegion;
rectRegion = CRect(rectClient.left - m_nWindowClipPad - 1, rectClient.top - m_nCaptionHeight - 2 - m_nWindowClipPad, rectClient.right + m_nWindowClipPad + 1, rectClient.bottom + m_nWindowClipPad + 1);

m_rgnWindow.Detach();
m_rgnWindow.CreateRectRgnIndirect(rectRegion);
.
.
.
// Call base version
CMDIChildWndEx::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
}
```

I can upload screenshots of what's happening if that would be helpful, but hopefully the description above does the trick.

I'd really appreciate any advice of examples of how to get this to work! Thank you.

Comment: In case anybody reads this in future and is looking for the solution, I eventually figured it out. It turns out that `SetWindowRgn` does not like negative coordinates (even though this is not documented) and truncates the region. So, if you are using `CreateRectRgnIndirect` with `SetWindowRgn` make sure you offset the `CRect` such that its top left is 0,0 first. Having changed that, and implemented `OnNcCalcSize` the custom drawn child frame is now working beautifully.

Comment: Hi Paul, is there any way that you could share your code for creating Windows 10 styled child windows? There are quite a few questions on SO and MSDN looking this, but I cannot find any usable sample code.